# Change CalendarView style

Tags: android, android-widget, android-styles, android-calendar

I'm trying to add a CalendarView in my application, which uses the Theme.Light theme. The problem is, the days numbers of this calendar are rendered in white, so while using a light theme, you can't see them.

Right now, I have the following code in my XML layout file :

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"/>
```

I tried to force the calendar theme like this :

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" />
```

But it doesn't change anything. I think I should do something with the android:dateTextAppearance property, so I tried this :

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:dateTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large.Inverse" />
```

but it doesn't do anything either.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In my project I defined the attribute "android:calendarViewStyle" in my theme.

```xml
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@android:Theme">
  <item name="android:calendarViewStyle">@style/Widget.CalendarView.Custom</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.CalendarView.Custom" parent="android:Widget.CalendarView">
    <item name="android:focusedMonthDateColor">@color/cs_textcolor</item>
    <item name="android:weekNumberColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:weekDayTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:dateTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
</style>
```

All styles possibilities are:

- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_showWeekNumber
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_firstDayOfWeek
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_minDate
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_maxDate
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_shownWeekCount
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_selectedWeekBackgroundColor
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_focusedMonthDateColor
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_unfocusedMonthDateColor
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_weekNumberColor
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_weekSeparatorLineColor
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_selectedDateVerticalBar
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_weekDayTextAppearance
- @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_dateTextAppearance

*note: if showWeekNumber not work as xml style, you can set in the code with setShowWeekNumber(true).*

Comment: Is it correct? <android.widget.CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:theme ="@style/Theme.Custom" />

Comment: unable to change the color theme using the above solution

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on this? Where do i use all those "@attr" stuff? I'm not familiar with that at all.

Comment: in my case it did change the style, but not as expected

Answer (score 17):

I've been having a lot of trouble as well. While not perfect, and I haven't figured out how to modify every aspect, I got close. This is how I did it, in the project's styles.xml I added these styles:

```
<style name="CalenderViewCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white_30</item>
</style>

<style name="CalenderViewDateCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="CalenderViewWeekCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_30</item>
</style>
```

Then, for the CalendarView I referenced those styles as so:

```
<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/CalenderViewCustom"
    android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewDateCustomText"
    android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewWeekCustomText"/>
```

You can add the other types of colors (primary/secondary) to CalenderViewCustom above.

Comment: Thank you it's still working as of 2021 ^^