# Changing color of single day in calendarview, android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, calendarview

I've got the calendarview in eclipse and now I'm trying to change the appearance of a single day to highlight dates. 
I didn't find any useful method [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html), only changes of appearances of whole weekdates or monthdates.
So is there a possibility to highlight a single day?

Also i know there are like 3 posts with the same issue, but none of them got answered.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412402/change-calendarview-style

Comment: If I interpret this right, he changes the appearance of all dates too, so this wouldn't be a solution to me, if I understood it wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could extend the native CalenderView to create your own CustomCalendarView and make any desired changes in appearance.

You can find the code for the native CalendarView [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/android/calendar/CalendarView.java).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know the native CalendarView. 
Still android should maybe implement a method for changing single day colors in CalendarView!

Comment: I find the calendar view very confusing to use. I don't understand why the user wants to scroll vertically or horizontally as if you are reading a foot-long text document. I find this not ergonomic at all. I am looking for ways on how to prevent calendar from being scrolled and to show only one month per view.

Comment: The CalendarView source link is dead.

Comment: Actual source code is here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/CalendarView.java

Answer (score 4):

You may do it by obtain the child views of the `CalendarView` and change  there configuations:

```
    final CalendarView calendar = new CalendarView(this);       
    java.lang.reflect.Field field = null;

    Class<?> cvClass = calendar.getClass();
    try {
        field = cvClass.getDeclaredField("mDayNamesHeader");    
        field.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    }

    ViewGroup tv = null;
    try {
        tv = (ViewGroup) field.get(calendar);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {} 
      catch (IllegalArgumentException ){}

    TextView k =  (TextView) tv.getChildAt(1);
    k.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Here You can find all declarations:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2888524e03896831f487e5dee63f18f1c33c0115/core/java/android/widget/CalendarView.java