# Android Calendar styling

Tags: android

I have tried this answer to change a calendarview's style in one of my layouts:
[Change CalendarView style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412402/change-calendarview-style) but eclipse is giving me the error saying the item's resources, such as styles, are undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **android:** **dateTextAppearence**, **android:focusedMonthDatecolor**, **android:selectedWeekBackgroundColor**, **android:unfocusedMonthDateColor**, **android:weekDayTextAppearance**, **android:weekNumberColor**, and **android:weekSeparatorLineColor** to change how your calendarview looks, however it would *technically* not be changing the style, per se.

For more information, check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html