# Edit background color of a day in calendar view

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

in my application, I have to show a calendar in which some days are colored differently (eg with a green background)
I entered the "calendar view" and I focused on the current date, but can not seem to color certain days from code. Can you give me some advice? (I don't want to use custom library)

```
CalendarView calendario = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
    Calendar Now = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendario.setDate(Now.getTimeInMillis()); //focus calendar view on today
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9869339/2556111

Comment: i don't have to change the color of the selected day, but the color day determined from code, such ass, 4 day in a week

Comment: Hi try to look at this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556254/android-calendarview-for-showing-events

Answer (score 1):

Almost impossible to do, try to use https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView, it works great. 
I switched from CalendarView to CompactCalendarView, and it solved most of my problems.