# How to change font size of calendarView android?

Tags: android, android-widget, calendarview

Hi I am working with calendar view. I want it's text to be 12sp but I am not be able to set it. I have tried for   android:dateTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
but it is not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412402/change-calendarview-style

Comment: It is not solving my problem Farouk. same issue again

Answer (score 2):

You should have been able to set

```
android:dateTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
```

Although unless you override, you won't be able to set the size of small.  Create an updated style in your styles which overrides parent "@android:style/TextAppearance.Small".  (i.e. styles/style.xml)

```
<style name="SmallerCalendarText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">8dp</item>
</style>
```

And now in your layout xml file for the CalendarView widget:

```
    <CalendarView
        ...
        android:dateTextAppearance="@style/SmallerCalendarText" />
```

Comment: How did you know to override that style element?  Im more interested in how one would arrive at this strategy.