# Date Picker Material Design issue in Android

Tags: android, datepicker, material-design, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am facing issue in Date Picker. View is cutting from bottom.

[image]

Here is my code  -

```
 <!-- Layout that will hold the content of the Tabs -->
            <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <!-- Layout for the DatePicker -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/date_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <DatePicker
                        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                        android:calendarViewShown="false" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Layout for the TimePicker -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/time_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TimePicker
                        android:id="@+id/time_picker"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

Please help me out.

**NOTE : Facing this issue in Lollipop and Marshmallow.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you can see the red circle in which the 29 date green circle is cutting from bottom.

Comment: It is your fault ... DataPicker + your tabs just are longer then Dialog size ... put DataPicker into ScrollView or use DP with calendar only

Comment: Please have a look of my code.

Comment: @Selvin I have added my full code, Please have a look. :)

Comment: Answear is pretty simply. Never, ever use date or time picker in nested layouts. Otherwise you would need to play with style and font sizes. Some hint here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412402/change-calendarview-style