# why my code don't show any color on my calendarView android

Tags: android, app-inventor

when i run my code hi show me standard CalendarView without any color.

ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)inputHV.getView();

```
simpleCalendarView = new CalendarView(context);

    simpleCalendarView.setFocusedMonthDateColor(11277846); // set the red color for the dates of  focused month
    simpleCalendarView.setUnfocusedMonthDateColor(Color.BLUE); // set the yellow color for the dates of an unfocused month
    simpleCalendarView.setSelectedWeekBackgroundColor(11277846); // red color for the selected week's background
    simpleCalendarView.setWeekSeparatorLineColor(Color.GREEN);
    simpleCalendarView.setShowWeekNumber(true);


    vg.addView(simpleCalendarView);
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9869339/5212133

Comment: im works on app-inventor extension i can't work on XML i need solution programmatically