# android - calendar view, how change color of specific dates?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to change colors of specific dates like shown in Image can I achieve this using android calendar view or I have to create my custom Calendar?

[image]

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: Check this out may be it will help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412402/change-calendarview-style