# How to set Custom font face for Calenderview?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-calendar, calendarview

How to set custom font face for calenderview? using "android:dateTextAppearance" i can only change the size or appearance and not font face.i have tried via asset. that also didnt work.please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9412402/7948109) question and it's answers, on how to style CalendarView in android

Comment: i checked already but i couldnt change font face.i can change small,medium but not the font like times new roman,tahoma,roboto etc.even i add ttf font in asset folder it also didnt work.kindly suggest me the solution,